# How do I validate that the input is numerical?

Tags: c, input

I have an assignment where the user must enter four inputs, one after another. They are:
character, float, float, int.

The main issue is how to check for errors and make sure the used entered valid input?

I have finished the character section but for the floats and ints, how can I check that only numbers are entered and print an error message if letters or symbols are entered?

Thought maybe `isdigit()` or `isaplha()` but unsure how to implement their use.

NOTE I have already used `scanf()` for the input but not sure how to check if input is valid?

Comment: How about `scanf` and checking the return value?

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? In order to keep the code consistent it's useful to see how you're approaching the problem.

Comment: @Mike Please stop adding tagging questions with [tag:homework]. It's a dead tag, and you're making work for those who are cleaning it up. See  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag/147125#comment421902_147125

Comment: @meagar - I've seen it being added to a number of newer posts so I was not aware it was dead. Is there a replacement, or is the concept of a "homework" question in general dead?

Answer (score 3):

If the user is required to enter a string, two floating point numbers and an integer, use

```
 char s[1024];
 float f1, f2;
 int i;

 if (sscanf (buff, "%s %f %f %d", s, &f1, &f2, &i) == 4) {
    /* Could scan values as expected. */
 } else {
    /* Input not as expected. */
 }
```

since `sscanf` returns the number of successfully scanned values. For the details, see the sscanf manual page. Note that scanning an unbounded string with `%s` has its problems with large inputs. This may not be an issue for homework assignments, but is definitely something to be aware of in production software.

Answer (score 2):

With `sscanf()`, you can try to parse the content of a string as some data type, like an integer (with the `%d` format specifier) or floating point number (with `%g`).

The return value of `sscanf()` tells you if it was successful in interpreting the text as the desired data.

You can also use `%n` to learn how many characters  `sscanf()` looked at, which is handy when you want to analyze in multiple steps.

Comment: so ive currently used:
fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
sscanf(buff, "%s%f%f%i", &letters, &start, &end, &inter);
how would i use the %d or %n to eliminate illegal characters from 'start'? could u show the code?

Comment: Try `if(sscanf(buff, "%s %f %f %i", &letters, &start, &end, &inter) < 4) { /* error */ }`.

Comment: so i ran it and entered:
abcd 4.5 4.6 5h 
and still got a successful message. the 'h' at the end is not allowed? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're getting your values right now other than you're using scanf() as you mentioned in your post. So lets say you're doing something like this:

```
char buf[100];     
scanf("%s", buf);
```

to get the float/int values. If you want to use `isdigit()` to verify they are all digit values you can loop as such:

```
int i = 0;

//need to check for a . for floats
//need to check for a - for negative numbers
while(isdigit(buf[i]) || buf[i] == '.' || buf[i] == '-') 
   i++;
if(i == strlen(buf))   // if we made it to the end of the string
   //we have all digits, do all digit code
else
   //there are numbers or symbols, ask for the number again, or terminate, or whatever
```

Comment: Happy to help, if it works for you please remember to accept the answer so others know your issue is closed.

Comment: See the gray outline of a check mark under the number next to the post? Click it and it becomes green. That accepts the answer. You can also click the up arrows by the numbers for answers that were helpful (or down arrows for answers that were not useful)